# wordpress theme not installed permission denied couldn't create directry. On my macbook air at localhost

Tags: php, wordpress-thesis-theme

Not able to install themes and plugins in WordPress. This show error has given below:

```
Error: Installation failed, Couldn't create a directory.
```

Comment: you may have write permission problems

Answer (score 0):

Give permissions to your project folder like:
1. sudo chown -R username:www-data /var/www/html
2. sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
3. sudo chmod g+w /var/www/html/wp-content
4. sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/wp-content/themes
5. sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins

then restart server:
sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: please format your answer and add an explanation of what does each command do